# Content of all Jquery Tabs loading for a second on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery for Tabs, everything works fine except that on a website refresh the content of all tabs is shown for a second, then everything jumps back to normal.
https://gyazo.com/3df254e9161955c2d3d1cc116f660abf

What exactly is the problem? I just can't identify it.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mechanics/segments_container.css"/>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                activate: function(event, ui) {
                    window.location.hash = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="tabs">

        <div class ="forum_switch_buttons_wrap">

          <ul style = "display:inline;">
            <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#General">General</a></li>
            <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#Gaming">Gaming</a></li>
            <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#Computing">Computing</a></li>
            <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#Graphics">Graphics</a></li>
            <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#Coding">Coding</a></li>
            <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#Market">Market</a></li>
            <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#Groups">Groups</a></li>
            <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#Premium">Premium</a></li>
            <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#Archive">Archive</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>

        <div class = "forum_wrap">

            <div class = "forum_change_height_left">

                <div class = "forum_container_left" style = "display:block;" >

                    <div class = "titlebar">

                        Forum

                    </div>

                    <div class = "forum_inner_container">

                        <div id="General">

                            General Content

                        </div>
                        <div id="Gaming">

                            Gaming Content

                        </div>
                        <div id="Computing">

                            Computing Content

                        </div>
                        <div id="Graphics">

                            Graphic Content

                        </div>
                        <div id="Coding">

                            Coding Content

                        </div>
                        <div id="Market">

                            Market Content

                        </div>
                        <div id="Groups">

                            Group Content

                        </div>
                        <div id="Premium">

                            Premium Content

                        </div>
                        <div id="Archive">

                            Archive Content

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class = "forum_change_height_right">

                <div class = "forum_container_right">

                    <div class = "titlebar">

                        Latest Posts

                    </div>

                    <div class = "forum_inner_container">

                        testtest

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>  

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more please? :)
I'm not the best with JS. :/

Comment: @samir `$(function(){ })` is exactly the same as `$(document).ready()`

Comment: So $(document).ready() won't work? Because I'm trying hard to paste it somewhere where it makes sense in my code but I just can't get it working. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply css to hide the content.

What is happening is the script doesn't fire until the whole  dom is `ready` so you are getting a "Flash of Unstyled Content".

A simple css fix:

```
.forum_inner_container > div{
    display:none
}

.forum_inner_container > div:first-child{
    display:block
}
```

If you use the same class `forum_inner_container` on other pages that don't have tabs just give each tab content element a common class and adjust rules above accordingly